# Ingest logs into Splunk through AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-sns, splunk, splunk-query

I'm planing to ingest my `Trend Micro Deep Security Agent` events into Splunk and only the possible option is forwarding events to AWS SNS topic. My question is, what is the recommended way to do this there after getting the events to SNS? As I could see, I need to create subscription in my `SNS topic` to send events to `AWS SQS` and then use the `Splunk Add-on for AWS` to pull the events. Are there anyone else have better idea on this or any other recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

refer to https://www.splunk.com/en_us/partners/solutions/aws/data-insights-tool.html for the recommended data ingestion methods for Splunk and AWS.

For high volume, you may want to look at kinesis sending data to HEC.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't know about this. But still I have a doubt, why I cannot directly use SQS via `AWS ADD-ON`? Should I send the logs through `Lambda`?

Comment: You can access SQS via the Splunk AWS Add-On, as documented at https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/AddOns/released/AWS/SQS . If the volume is low, this approach is fine, as the add-on will grab the latest data whenever it runs (fairly frequently). If the volume is high, then the add-on may not grab enough data consistently, and could lag. Hence why the SNS->SQS->Lambda->HEC approach is recomended for high volume applications, as this doesnt rely on the add-on to pull data (the data is pushed into HEC)

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for your response. Will work on the said approach and update in here.